# Software Project Management Software

Tags: project-management

I have recently been tasked with writing a fairly large (for 1 person) program and would like to know what is the best software to use to be able to manage this project. Something that I can list what needs to be done and check it off when it is done, something to keep me on track.

Comment: Anything but Microsoft Project...

Comment: @aaronnaught, I'd take Project over Clarity (which is what we use) any day! (not that either would be my choice!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) user here.  Does exactly what you're asking and if there's just going to be one user then you can use it for [free](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/StudentAndStartup.html).

Another option for the basic task scheduling/prioritization duties is [SmartSheet](http://www.smartsheet.com/) - never clicked with me personally but a lot of people seem to like it.  It's worth checking out as an alternative.

Comment: I hear about Fogbugz alot on the podcast and thought it was way out of my league but I just set it up and it is exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can check out this one too, simple and easy to use http://checkvist.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you find free and open source project management software, you can use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) or [Collabtive](http://collabtive.o-dyn.de). We use both of them for project management activity.

Otherwise, if you have money and require professional service, why not try FogBugz or BaseCamp for free trial?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Mylyn if you are into Eclipse. Trac is a great ticket/task tracking system.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [XPlanner](http://www.xplanner.org/) it's neat and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

We use http://easyprojects.net/ and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio there are some task list features built in I'm sure some other IDE's also have similar features.  In the company I work for MS project is the defacto standard.  I don't really see the value in it for a one person project.  I use [Todolist](http://www.abstractspoon.com/) for personal Time management.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org).

It's a source code management system with built in ticket system and wiki.

It's trivial to get it working (just one binary file).

It's crossplatform.

It stores the whole repository into an SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

- [Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com/)
- [BugZilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/)